# Syntax Error in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Probably an easy fix but from what I can see from examples this should be working!

```
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_11` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_11_url` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_11_desc` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_12` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_12_url` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_12_desc` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_13` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_13_url` varchar(500);
ADD `linktitle_13_desc` varchar(500);
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change the all but the last semi-colon to commas. Also, in the future, always post the error message. We are *not* mind readers.

Comment: @JohnConde Tried that, still getting the same error! Should have attached it, sorry! Here it is: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"relevant_topics" ADD `linktitle_11` varchar(500), ADD `linktitle_11_url` var' at line 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need quotes for the table name and each `add` should be separated with `,`

```
ALTER TABLE relevant_topics
ADD `linktitle_11` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_11_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_11_desc` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12_desc` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13_desc` varchar(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

as it is now you are only creating the column linktitle_11 right? a semicolon ends your sql statement and there is no sql statement that is simply called add, your alter table statement is ended as soon as you add the first column
you need to either do:

```
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD (`linktitle_11` varchar(500),
 `linktitle_11_url` varchar(500),
 `linktitle_11_desc` varchar(500),
 `linktitle_12` varchar(500),
 `linktitle_12_url` varchar(500),
 `linktitle_12_desc` varchar(500),
 `linktitle_13` varchar(500),
 `linktitle_13_url` varchar(500));
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_11` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_11_url` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_11_desc` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_12` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_12_url` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_12_desc` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_13` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_13_url` varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE "relevant_topics" 
ADD `linktitle_13_desc` varchar(500);
```

Though I don't know which would be the safest way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can use tilde for quotes if required

```
ALTER TABLE `relevant_topics`
ADD `linktitle_11` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_11_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_11_desc` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12_desc` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13_desc` varchar(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE relevant_topics
ADD `linktitle_11` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_11_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_11_desc` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_12_desc` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13_url` varchar(500),
ADD `linktitle_13_desc` varchar(500);
```